# Is it permissible to exercise if it stimulates the prostate, building up sexual tension?

Tags: sex, masturbation, morality

When I was working out, I suddenly felt a strange feeling down. At first, I thought that it is coming from my abdomen, but then I realised that sexual tension was building up, so I stopped doing this exercise.

After reading about this a little on the internet, I realised that the reason for this is because the exercise was exercising the core and putting pressure on the pelvis region, stimulating the prostate gland and building up sexual tension.

Is it permissable to do such an exercise, provided that my intention is not masturbation? What if 'maniy' was released?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongly suggest you to take our [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about our site and model.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it was unintentional, and doing the exercise again won't repeat the same problem, then, yes, it should be permissible. I'd stay away though. I believe there was a hadith of staying away from that which you doubt to remain in favour of that which does not give you doubt.